# What is FixedUpdate and How it runs in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Maybe this is one of the simplest question that What is `FixedUpdate` and how it runs, Yes I know that but with some confusion:

- FixedUpdate is independent from the frame rate.
- The time interval is to call FixedUpdate is constant; as it is called
  on a reliable timer (**Which timer? Like Update is run per frame how FixedUpaate Run**).
- FixedUpdate can be called multiple times per frame if frame rate is
  low or it may not be called per frame if the frame rate will be
  high. (**Why it is effecting with frame rate if it runs on a reliable timer**)
- So, it is quite possible that FixedUpdate will be called more than
  Update (**Yes i can understand that if it is running after specific time then it can run more than update, Right?**).

Comment: https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate

Comment: It is not affecting the framerate at all. It runs independant from the framerate that's why if you're stuck on a frame, the FixedUpdate will still be called. That's why you should use FixedUpdate for physic stuff because you don't want the physics of a game to be slowed down by your framerate. That's also the reason it can run more than update, because it can run multiple times **per frame**.